# SCP prevent user from changing s3:PutBucketPublicAccessBlock" only if the setting is currently already checked

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I currently have this Service Control Policy (SCP) in place to prevent user from changing `s3:PutBucketPublicAccessBlock`, but I only want to deny the action if the setting is currently already checked. Is there a way I can put in a boolean expression to do this?

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutBucketPublicAccessBlock"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Deny"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No.

The Condition keys listed in [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon S3 - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html) do not show an option for specifying a current value as a condition of access.